# It's search repeatedly in the folder

Tags: c#

Files and folders before the set date are deleted codes.

However, there is a problem.

I want to check the file and delete in the root folder and check the file and delete in the subfolder only once

but check the file in the root folder after delete the file in the subfolder.

I do not want to repeatedly check the file that I already confirmed.

```
public void FolderAndFileDelete(DirectoryInfo directoryInfo, SQLiteConnection connection, HashSet<string> splitedExtension, DateTime setTime)
    {
        FileInfo[] files = directoryInfo.GetFiles();
        DirectoryInfo[] directoryInfos = directoryInfo.GetDirectories();

        if (files != null)
        {
            foreach (var file in files)
            {
                file.Delete();
            }

            if (subFolderRemoveCheckBox.Checked == true)
            {
                foreach (DirectoryInfo subfolder in directoryInfos)
                {
                    if (subfolder.GetFiles().Length == 0)
                    {
                        subfolder.Delete();
                    }

                    else if (subfolder.GetFiles().Length != 0)
                    {
                        this.FolderAndFileDelete(subfolder, connection, splitedExtension, setTime);
                    }
                    if (!subfolder.Exists)
                        return;

                }

            }
        }
    }
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: i'm sorry, but its unclear what you are asking, can you spend some time making your question more specific as its not articulated very well

Comment: you can remove the `connection` argument since it is never used

Comment: you also never use `splittedExtension` argument, so that can be removed

Comment: you can also remove `setTime`, since that is never used

Comment: And finally, to remove a directory **and** all the contents (files and sub-directories), just pass `true` to `Delete`. For example: `if (subFolderRemoveCheckBox.Checked == true) subfolder.Delete(true);`

Comment: @RufusL Thanks your comment. another argument is already using my code.
Failed to clear parameters while switching to sample code.

Comment: The logic you have above will not attempt to delete any sub directories unless there is also one or more files in the `directoryInfo`. Is that by design? If not, you should move the logic that deletes sub-directories outside the logic that determines if there are any files to delete.

Comment: `directoryInfo.GetFiles()` will never return a `null` object (if there are no files, it returns an empty list - see the documentation [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.directory.getfiles?view=netframework-4.7.2#System_IO_Directory_GetFiles_System_String_)), so that `if` condition is not necessary (it will always be `true`). You may as well remove that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method can be reduced to something a little simpler, since you can pass `true` to the `Delete` method of a `DirectoryInfo` if you want it to remove all files and sub-directories. Note that I added a `bool` parameter to specify if sub-folders should be removed, so you would pass `subFolderRemoveCheckBox.Checked` for this argument:

```
public void DeleteContents(DirectoryInfo directoryInfo, bool includeSubFolders = false)
{
    foreach (var file in directoryInfo.GetFiles())
    {
        file.Delete();
    }

    if (includeSubFolders)
    {
        foreach (var subDirectory in directoryInfo.GetDirectories())
        {
            subDirectory.Delete(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I solved it simply with your help. Thanks.
I did not think that 'Delete(true)'.